# Getting undefined from process.env[serviceBus]

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables

I am working on BE side of a project. I have many service bus URLs in my env and wanted to get them dynamically.

Env looks like this

```
SB1 = 'Endpoint=link1'
SB2 = 'Endpoint=link2'
```

sample code of mine

```
const serviceBus = "SB1";
const connectionString = process.env[serviceBus];
```

This logic is working fine when I run locally, but when I deploy my code. It is not working.
Please correct my approach or suggest me a better approach to do this.

Comment: Most likely `.env` file is not deployed (because it's normal) and you should set your env variables in the admin panel of the host provider

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Konrad , 
but all other env's are working like process.env.SB1 works locally as well as when deployed, the problem comes in this usage-only process.env["SB1"]

Answer (score -1):

Hi first make sure you have the .env file also uploaded on the server because many times by default project setting .env files are added to gitignore.

Also if you are using express.js then make sure that you make your .env file available by `require('dotenv').config()`

and install dotenv by command `npm i dotenv`

you can use it like `process.env.serviceBus`